# List files starting from the src folder

Tags: java, eclipse, list, file, directory

I want to list all files, that are located in a folder named *icons*. But the special feature is, that I want to start ot from the *src* folder in Eclipse.

I want to use something like this:

```
File f = new File("src/icons");
File[] fileArray = f.listFiles();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried that code?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is non trivial, because the `src` folder gets compiled into the class files, and probably packed in a jar file. All the non `.java` files are simply getting copied to the jar file. So, you want to list the files inside the jar file in fact, if there is a jar file. If there is no jar file, you want to list the files that are somewhere between the compiled files.

Why would you try to solve that? Make it yourself easy and ship your application with a separate `resources` folder or something like that. However, if you don't need to list the files, and you know exactly which files you want, you can just grab the file from easily independent of the fact that it is in a jar file or not, using this:

```
InputStream in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/delete.png");
```

Comment: I am working on a Eclipse plugin, so there will be no jar file. Everything will happen within the Eclipse IDE. For me it is important to have a list, where all the files, that are stored in the icons folder (src/icons) are stored.

Comment: Eclipse plugins are also shipped in a JAR file. Check that out. They are at the eclipse folder /plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
String path = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() + "icons";
File f = new File(path);
File[] fileArray = f.listFiles();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, you did not simply mean a directory called src, you meant the source code directory of the project/running class.